# How to batch process some frames with different dimension but same name pattern some how by R

Tags: r, dataframe

In the R environment, I have already have some variable, their name:

```
id_01_r 
id_02_l 
id_05_l 
id_06_r
id_07_l
id_09_1
id_11_l
```

So, **their pattern** seems like `id_` and follows two figures, then `_` and `r` or `l` randomly.
Each of them corresponds to one frame but different `dim()` output.

Also, there are some other variables in the environment, so first I should extract these frames. For this, I'm going to adopt:

```
> a <- list(ls()[grep("id*",ls())])` #a little sample for just id* I know
```

But, this function put them as one element, so I don't think it's    good way

```
> length(a)     [1] 1
```

I know how to read them in like below, but now for extact and same processes, I'm so confused.

```
i_set <- Sys.glob(paths='mypath/////id*.txt')
for (i in i_set) {
    assign(substring(i, startx, endx),read.table(file=i,header=F))
    }
```

**Here, the key point is I want to do a series of same data processing for each of these frames. But based on these, what can I do instead of one by one?**
**Thanks your kind consideration.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
id_01_r <- iris
id_02_l <- mtcars
foo <- 42

vars <- grep("^id_\\d{2}_[rl]$", ls(), value = TRUE)
# [1] "id_01_r" "id_02_l"

process_data <- function(df) {
  dim(df)
}

processed_data <- lapply(
  mget(vars),
  process_data
)

# $id_01_r
# [1] 150   5
# 
# $id_02_l
# [1] 32 11
```

Comment: This example is so great to reply all I mentioned, you are so clever! This output is a list length is two. Do you know how to make processed_data the output one frame? Two col, id_01_r, id_02_l

Comment: Sure, it might look like: `as.data.frame(processed_data)`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I see, since actually, I plan to choose one certain col from each frame, make them add NA then become same length, then, add them one by one to build a new frame. Do you think  as.data.frame() will let them become disorder?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Forcing a "ragged array" (columns of different lengths) into a data frame structure is generally a bad idea, though it's feasible by adding `NA`s like you suggest. Better to keep a regular list.

Comment: I see, I'm not just force to build, here will some prcess in 'process_data', the NA will reflect the truth, means this sample does't have something

Comment: It's will let the certain col in these frames to compare one long name col, just a vector

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. But don't worry the details, I just don't know the main pathway and you just now solve it:)